# How to execute a command during war creation?

Tags: grails

My environment:  Grails v2.1.1

I need to run a small utility app during the war process.  This app generates files that I want included in my war file.  I've tried putting code in BuildConfig.groovy's grails.war.resources, but I'm not seeing an error, or the files I am expecting to be created.

Does anyone know how I can execute this utility app so that its output is in my war?

This is the command as run inside a terminal instance:

```
sencha app build -e production -d $stagingDir/production
```

Here's my attempt to run it via `grails.war.resources` in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->

//calling echo() does nothing.  I don't see the comment in the build output
echo(message:'executing grails.war.resources')
def outputDir =  new File("${stagingDir.getParentFile().getPath()}/target/ranForReal")

def command = """sencha app build -e testing -d ${outputDir.getPath()}"""

def executionDir = new File("${stagingDir.getParentFile().getPath()}/web-app")

def proc = command.execute(null,executionDir)

proc.waitFor()

//my desperate attempt to see if anything is happening.  I'd expect an error here
def x = 1/0

// Obtain status and output
println "return code: ${ proc.exitValue()}"
println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}" // *out* from the external program is *in* for groovy

//this for loop does work and does remove servlet jars, so I know this closure is called.
for (name in ['servlet']) {
    delete {
        fileset dir: "$stagingDir/WEB-INF/lib/",
                includes: "$name*.jar"
    }
}

}
```

Is `grails.war.resources` the way to go?

**Update**

For posterity, here is my somewhat complex example, using the answer below.

from *`_Events.groovy`* file

```
/**
 * Generate an optimized version of the sencha app.
 */
eventCreateWarStart = {warName, stagingDir ->
    //argsMap contains params from command line, e.g 'war --sencha.env=production'
def senchaEnvironment = argsMap["sencha.env"] ?: 'testing'

    //println is the only way I've found to write to the console.
println "running sencha optimizer code for $senchaEnvironment environment..."

ant.exec(outputproperty: "cmdOut", executable:'sencha',
        dir:"$stagingDir",failOnError:true){
    arg(value:'app')
    arg(value:'build')
    arg(value:"-e $senchaEnvironment" )
}

println "${ant.project.properties.cmdOut}"

println'completed sencha optimization process.'

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put an `eventCreateWarStart` in your `scripts/_Events.groovy`.  This event receives two parameters, the name of the WAR and the stagingDir

```
eventCreateWarStart = { warName, stagingDir ->
  // ..
}
```

You have access to the `ant` variable giving you an `AntBuilder` so you can do stuff like

```
ant.exec(executable:'sencha') {
  arg(value:'app')
  arg(value:'build')
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Ian, where exactly is `stagingDir`?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel I'm not sure, I suspect it's somewhere under `target`, or failing that `~/.grails`, but the point is that it's the directory which will get zipped up to produce the WAR file, so anything you copy into it will end up in the WAR.

Comment: Aha, anyway I have a feeling that it's `web-app`. Will get back to you when I confirm.

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel the `stagingDir` shouldn't be `web-app` itself, it should be a temporary location which the contents of `web-app` (amongst other things) will be copied into in order to build the WAR.