# How do I make Grails execute shell commands just before creating war file?

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0

Let's say I want to do `git pull origin master` just before preparing a war file.

Comment: You would have to write a batch/shell script to do all of it via CLI, if you are using Jenkins to work on repos.. then take a look at jenjir plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do something before the war is packaged, use the "CreateWarStart" event, e.g. as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585434/how-to-execute-a-command-during-war-creation). To actually run the Git command, use can use Groovy's ability to execute commands as strings, e.g. `'git pull origin master'.execute()` (see [the docs here](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute%28%29)) or do it more programmatically with `ProcessBuilder` like you would in Java, and optionally wrapped in a shell script to abstract the details away from the web app code.